# Angular CLI , Node v8 and npm 5. Issue while installing packages in restricted network environment

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, angular-cli, node-sass

I have upgrade my nodejs to v 8.1 and using npm 5, For Angular CLI latest

```
$ node --version && npm --version
v8.1.4
5.0.3
```

While running installation command I am getting below exception.

Our company has some restriction on network, So I manually downloaded **win32-x64-57_binding.node** and set path in environment

```
    /c/Projects/ced/frontend (Angular4Upgrade) $ npm i

    > node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Projects\ced\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/install.js

    node-sass build Binary found at C:\Projects\DA\Node\win32-x64-57_binding.node

    > node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\Projects\ced\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/build.js

    module.js:487
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'cross-spawn'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\ced\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\scripts\build.js:8:11)
        at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\{userfolder}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-07-26T05_02_42_055Z-debug.log

    /c/Projects/ced/frontend (Angular4Upgrade)
    $ npm install cross-spawn

    > node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Projects\ced\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/install.js

    node-sass build Binary found at C:\Projects\DA\Node\win32-x64-57_binding.node

    > node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall C:\Projects\ced\frontend\node_modules\node-sass
    > node scripts/build.js

    Binary found at C:\Projects\DA\Node\win32-x64-57_binding.node
    Testing binary
    Binary has a problem: { Error: Cannot find module 'lodash.assign'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
        at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\ced\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\lib\index.js:7:12)
        at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
    Building the binary locally
    module.js:487
        throw err;
        ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
        at Function.resolve (internal/module.js:18:19)
        at build (C:\Projects\ced\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\scripts\build.js:59:23)
        at testBinary (C:\Projects\ced\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\scripts\build.js:147:12)
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Projects\ced\frontend\node_modules\node-sass\scripts\build.js:155:1)
        at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 postinstall script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have googled for various related types of error and most are saying delete npm-cache and node_module folder of project.

So I did this but same issue exist. And I don't have admin access as well.

Let me know, if you need more info

Comment: do you try "npm cache clear" and run it again?

Comment: Using NPM 5 so it doesn't support clear, but manually deleted npm-cache folder, not working that.